Can we modify R7RS implementation of the derived expression type `do` to finish SICP exercise 4.9?
This is one follow-up question of this QA where how syntax-rules works has been known owing to Shawn. As someone told me before, one different question although somewhat related should be posted as one new QA.
Exercise 4.9:

Exercise 4.9. Many languages support a variety of iteration constructs, such as do, for, while, and until. In Scheme, iterative processes can be expressed in terms of ordinary procedure calls, so special iteration constructs provide no essential gain in computational power. On the other hand, such constructs are often convenient. Design some iteration constructs, give examples of their use, and show how to implement them as derived expressions.

Here I choose to implement do as the derived expression with the same syntax as MIT/GNU Scheme:

do ((variable init step) …) (test expression …) command …

R7RS implements as the following:
(define-syntax do
   (syntax-rules ()
     ((do ((var init step ...) ...)
         (test expr ...)
         command ...)
     (letrec
       ((loop
         (lambda (var ...)
           (if test
               (begin
                 (if #f #f)
                 expr ...)
               (begin
                 command
                 ...
                 (loop (do "step" var step ...)
                       ...))))))
       (loop init ...)))
     ((do "step" x)
     x)
     ((do "step" x y)
     y)))

which works for one specific code with possible name collision due to loop (as Shawn points out in the  reference QA, this actually won't happen due to mechanism used by syntax-rules):
(define test (vector 3))
(do ((loop (make-vector 5))
      (i 0 (+ i 1)))
    ((begin 
      (set! test loop)
      (= i 5)) (list loop test))
   (vector-set! loop i i))

This name collision can be shown by the naive replacement for the above template:
(letrec
  ((loop
    (lambda (loop i)
      (if (begin (set! test loop) (= i 5))
          (begin
            (if #f #f)
            (list loop test))
          (begin
            (vector-set! loop i i)
            (loop loop (+ i 1)))))))
  (loop (make-vector 5) 0))


As R7RS says:

definitions for the derived expression types in terms of the primitive expression types

and the book says:

a procedure cond->if that transforms cond expressions into if expressions
Expressions (such as cond) that we choose to implement as syntactic transformations are called derived expressions

So IMHO the above template can be the solution if not using letrec which is not taught in SICP up to that exercise. I used named let while schemewiki (see woofy's implementation) uses thunk. So we can change the above letrec part as one of the following:
(let loop 
 ((var init) ...)
   (if test
       ; ...... same as the above corresponding part
       ))

((lambda ()
  (define (loop var ...)
    (if test
      ; ...... same as the above corresponding part
      ))
      (loop init ...)))

Then we can transform those templates including the template for (do "step" x) into one conversion code block like cons->if in the book:
;; based on https://github.com/xxyzz/SICP/blob/2decd1017f898529340dd07e73224f2e750b65b8/4_Metalinguistic_Abstraction/4.1_The_Metacircular_Evaluator/Exercise_4_9.rkt#L19-L38

;; from book
(define (make-lambda parameters body)
  (cons 'lambda (cons parameters body)))

(define (make-if predicate consequent alternative)
  (list 'if predicate consequent alternative))

(define (last-exp? seq) (null? (cdr seq)))
(define (first-exp seq) (car seq))
(define (sequence->exp seq)
  (cond ((null? seq) seq)
        ((last-exp? seq) (first-exp seq))
        (else (make-begin seq))))
(define (make-begin seq) (cons 'begin seq))

;; 
(define null '())
(define (make-define id expr)
  (cons 'define (cons id expr)))

(define (do->combination exp)
  (let ((var-list (map car (cadr exp)))
        (init-list (map cadr (cadr exp)))
        (intermediate-step-list (map cddr (cadr exp)))
        (stop?-expr (caaddr exp))
        (finish-expr (cdaddr exp))
        (expr (cdddr exp)))
    (let ((step-list 
            (map 
              (lambda (var step) 
                (if (null? step)
                  var
                  (car step))) 
              var-list intermediate-step-list)))
      (list
        (make-lambda null
                      (list
                        (make-define
                          (cons 'loop var-list)
                          (list
                            (make-if stop?-expr
                                    (sequence->exp finish-expr)
                                    (sequence->exp
                                      (append expr
                                              (list (cons 'loop
                                                          step-list)))))))
                        (cons 'loop init-list)))))))

expected behavior:
(assert 
  (equal? 
    (do->combination 
      '(do ((loop (make-vector 5))
            (i 0 (+ i 1)))
          ((begin 
            (set! test loop)
            (= i 5)) (list loop test))
        (vector-set! loop i i)))
    '((lambda () 
      (define (loop loop i) 
        (if (begin (set! test loop) (= i 5)) 
          (list loop test) 
          (begin (vector-set! loop i i) (loop loop (+ i 1))))) 
      (loop (make-vector 5) 0)))))
;Unspecified return value

Q:
Can the above do->combination which just implements the modified template version (define (loop var ...) ......) as the solution to exercise 4.9 although we need syntax-rules to avoid the name collision of loop? If not, how to get one solution to that exercise which avoids the name collision problem?

I don't know how to avoid the name collision caused by that artificial weird demo without using syntax-rules. Maybe as Will Ness says, we need to avoid that collision between the global variable and the local variable manually although the collision is not that type for the above one.

I'm not sure using define inside lambda is possible, but if it is, probably shouldn't be done anyway - redefining global name's value like that.

The collision above is between the symbol loop used by the argument of do->combination and the symbol used inside do->combination. Then when that expression is interpreted by the interpreter, collision is between procedure name and formal parameter name.
